# What to do when a duplicate is better than the original?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, flagging, duplicates

*I thought I remembered a similar discussion to this earlier, but can't find it now.  If this is a duplicate, please let me know.*

---

The community is pretty on top of things when it comes to flagging duplicates, which is good.  But sometimes you might have someone who puts a lot of thought and energy into a puzzle, and it turns out to be a duplicate of a substandard 30-second post that was previously made (same puzzle premise, but different story/presentation).

I don't think both should be kept open, but it seems that in the interests of quality, it would make more sense to keep the new post rather than the old one.

Is there policy for this situation?  We don't want to lose potentially valuable answers to the older question, but we also want the best quality for our questions.

#### Edit:

It appears this question has been answered here: [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643)

Comment: I think that in this specific case the old one should be closed since it was already marked as possible duplicates of various questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75885/271002

Comment: @Loong You linked to a [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75885/what-if-the-duplicate-is-better-than-the-original) of a [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55251/opinions-on-closing-an-older-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-question) of a [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/closing-an-earlier-post-as-a-duplicate-of-a-later-one) of the [original](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha)

Comment: Personally I'd say close the old question for bad quality and don't touch the new one, but that's just me. And in the situation your talking about, my question is a **variation**!

Comment: @warspyking , but is it enough of a variation to stand on it's own? if it's not then it likely is closer to a duplicate than not.

Comment: @moonbutt74 It has a different answer than the duplicate. The contents are entirely different. There is an added step to it. The only similarity is the 3rd step!

Comment: @Anachor Can you please post a link to the "specific case" (presumably a puzzle)? Or are you referring to the current meta post?